# How can i reduce my 275MB Hello World Electron package size?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-packager

I am currently developing a simple Hello World app using Angular and Electron (following this guide: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/). The steps are very simple:

- i created a new folder with Angular cli;
- i installed electron in the development environment using `npm install electron --save-dev`;
- i installed electron-packager with `npm install electron-packager -g` and `npm install electron-packager --save-dev`;
- i built the executable for Windows using `npm run build && npm run electron`.

However, even if the app is totally basic, i obtain a final folder of **275MB**.

I understand that Electron requires the whole Chromium and NodeJS thing to work, but on https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003 and other pages i read that people manage to obtain packages of ~30MB or at least 100MB, which is still preferable to 275MB. Can someone help me and explain me how to do that?

In case you need it, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "npm run build && npm run electron"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "electron": "^7.1.8",
    "electron-packager": "^14.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the `--prod` tag to your build command, you should get a smaller folder size.
You can see more build tags that might help you here: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: Just tried and obtained 260MB. Better, but still not the result i hoped for :/

Comment: You might be able to use the --buildOptimizer tag as well